# Google cloud functions Firebase Update FieldValue.increment(1) using NodeJS - TypeError: FieldValue.increment is not a function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im using NodeJs within google cloud functions and I want to increase the value of one parameter in one document

I initiate Firestore:

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const PROJECTID = 'XXXX';     
const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: PROJECTID,
  timestampsInSnapshots: true    
});
```

And my .get() and .set() functions work correctly. But when I try to update a value incrementing it, I get errors with FieldValue.increment

I've tried:

```
await snapshot.ref.update({ parameter: FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

adding:

```
const FieldValue = require('firebase-admin').firestore.FieldValue;

await snapshot.ref.update({ parameter: FieldValue.increment(1) });
```

as explained in other sites, and:

```
documentRef.update(
  'parameter', Firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
)
```

as explained in https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/fieldvalue

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
increment = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
await snapshotRef.update({ parameter: increment });
```

But none work.

Error:

TypeError: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function

or

TypeError: FieldValue.increment is not a function

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.5.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1"
  }
```

Comment: The last one should be valid. Have you tried restarting the emulators? and try `const inc = require("firebase-admin").firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);`. If that doesnt work, please share your Firebase Admin version from package.json

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Please provide more context on the error log and full context of your function.

Comment: Error: TypeError: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment is not a function

Dependencies:
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.5.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1"
  }
}

Comment: You're `firebase-admin` version is old. I reproduced your error when using that version. Consider upgrading it to the latest by using this command: `npm i firebase-admin@latest`. The latest version solves the issue. Also, to add, `@google-cloud/firestore` and `firebase-admin` are different. `@google-cloud/firestore` also have `FieldValue`. Which of the two will you be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `increment()` was added to Firestore SDK in April 2019 as mentioned in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#March_28_2019) but Firebase Admin `6.5.1` was released in January 2019. Upgrading to latest version should resolved this issue.

Comment: Yep, updated dependency to "firebase-admin": "^11.0.1" and run the command @MarcAnthonyB posted: `npm i firebase-admin@latest`
Then:
`const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');`

`documentRef.update({parameter: Firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)})`

Works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this as a community wiki. Command to update to the latest Firebase Admin version.

```
npm i firebase-admin@latest
```

You could also modify the specific package in `package.json` by changing the version to the latest. See sample below:

```
"firebase-admin": "latest"
```

and then run

```
npm install
```

Also, for best practice, always remove the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and then run `npm install` before you deploy your app.